# More complex joins with mql

Tags: freebase, mql

I tried to find actors sharing the same first movie. 
It was easy to find first movies of all actors.

```
[{
    "type": "/film/actor",
    "name": null,
    "/film/actor/film": [{
      "film": [{
        "name":          null,
        "initial_release_date": null
      }],
      "sort":  "film.initial_release_date",
      "limit": 1
    }]
}]
```

After that I wanted to make a kind of intersection of results of two queries. As a start,  I noticed an example in the query editor at freebase.com where we need two actors participating in the same movie

```
[{
  "a:starring": [{
    "actor": "Joe Pesci"
  }],
  "b:starring": [{
    "actor": "Robert de Niro"
  }],
  "name": null,
  "id":   null,
  "starring": [{
    "actor": null
  }],
  "type": "/film/film"
}]
```

But when I tried to make similar changes prefixing my two identical queries with something like "a:film", "b:film" there was always error. Probably I'm too used to SQL and think in terms of temporal sub-queries and I should think some other way.

Answer (score 1):

MQL doesn't allow you to constrain two things to be equal, so you can't do this entirely in MQL, but you can get all the data that you need to filter things with a simple post-processing stage.

You've got all the actors and their first movies, so you just need to reuse that subquery to ask for the first movies of all the other actors in that set of movies.

Your query will look like the one below.  You then need to iterate over the matches and look for ones your inner actor's first film is the same as your outer actor's first film using something like this:

```
film_id = film.film.mid
for appearance in film.film.starring:
  if appearance.actor.film.film.mid == film_id:
    print "%s and %s shared the same first film %s" % (mid,appearance.actor.mid,film_id)
```

Note that you should do your comparison on the IDs, not the names so you don't get false matches for different films which have the same name (not common, but possible).

Here's the MQL to generate the information you need:

```
[{
  "type":  "/film/actor",
  "name":  null,
  "mid":   null,
  "film": {
    "film": {
      "name":          null,
      "mid":           null,
      "initial_release_date": null,
      "starring": [{
        "actor": {
          "name": null,
          "mid":  null,
          "film": {
            "film": {
              "name":          null,
              "mid":           null,
              "initial_release_date": null
            },
            "sort":  "film.initial_release_date",
            "limit": 1
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    "sort":  "film.initial_release_date",
    "limit": 1
  },
  "limit": 2
}]​
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. Looking at your query it seemed that allowing inner initial_release_date to reference outer would be great to allow such queries. This would be in some way identical to sql approach when no matter what the nesting levels is a sub-query can reference a field from outer dataset